# How to center a node between two subtrees with `forest`?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I have the following tree, which I drew using the package `forest`:

```
\documentclass[border=2ex]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} for tree={grow'=north, math content}
    [u
      [v_1]
      [\cdots, no edge]
      [f
        [w_1]
        [\cdots, no edge]
        [w_m]
      ]
      [\cdots, no edge]% not centered :(
      [g
        [w_1']
        [\cdots, no edge]
        [w_n']
      ]
      [\cdots, no edge]
      [v_k]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]
I hope my tree syntax is clear enough (it was originally a one-liner...). As you can see, the `\cdots` in the middle is not centered, which is what I would like. I'm not too certain how to approach this, as I'm sure there's something in `forest` that I do not know about which solves this problem for me. Could anyone point me towards a solution?

As a bonus, I would also be interested in understanding *why* this behavior occurs :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for providing a minimal example document!